# How to replace App Logo with hamburger menu title on Action Bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-actionbaractivity, hamburger-menu

I have tried a lot but didn't reached to any result till now,
I made a hamburger menu and I am able to change the title on the action bar but for the first menu I need an Image to be displayed which I did successfully, but I want that Image to be replaced by the hamburger menu title when I switch to other fragments of hamburger, when I Apply Image then titles are not shown on any other fragment's action bar
Below is my xml for drawer layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#ffffff"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:background="#5D5D5D"/>
```

My xml for showing image on action bar

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/home"
                />
            <!--<ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/search"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>-->
    </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My NavigationDrawer Activity

```
 package com.statzhub.Home.Hamburger.ui;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.statzhub.Home.Hamburger.adapaters.NavigationDrawerAdapter;
import com.statzhub.Home.Hamburger.model.NavigationDrawerItem;
import com.statzhub.Home.HomeFragment;
import com.statzhub.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String[] drawerTitles ;
    private TypedArray drawerIcons ;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ArrayList<NavigationDrawerItem> navigationItems;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private FragmentManager fragManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);

        // get array of string and images to be displayed in drawer list
        drawerTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items);
        drawerIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        //create array of getter setter class
        navigationItems = new ArrayList<NavigationDrawerItem>();
        // add items
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            navigationItems.add(new NavigationDrawerItem(drawerTitles[i],drawerIcons.getResourceId(i, 0)));
        }
        // recycle typed array
        drawerIcons.recycle();
        // set adapter
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new NavigationDrawerAdapter(this, navigationItems));

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        setupActionBar();
//        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);

        mDrawerToggle =  new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.menu_icon,// navigation menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name// nav open or close description for accessibility
        ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view){
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getTitle());
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            public void onDrawerOpen(View view){
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getTitle());
                invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }
        };

//        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//      set default page on navigation drawer
        fragManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame,new HomeFragment()).commit();
//      set functionality on click of drawer items
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        displayView(position);

            }


        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {

        }return true;

    }
    private void displayView(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        // replace fragments by current one
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new SearchFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new FollowingFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new FAQFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        if(fragment != null) {



            // put fragment in frame container
            fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment).commit();
            // update selected item and close drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position,true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
//            setTitle(drawerTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }


    }


    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        super.setTitle(title);
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    private void setupActionBar() {

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#5D5D5D")));

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        TextView titleTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);

//      showing search on action bar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(getSupportActionBar().getDisplayOptions()
                | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT
                | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        layoutParams.rightMargin = 20;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(imageView);

    }


}
```

I want Image to be displayed on HomeFragment and titles in other fragment
I am using 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1' library for action bar
and I want my search image should always be there for all fragment
any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks